# Is there a way to uniquely identify a static library at runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, unix, clang

With dynamic/shared libraries we can retrieve the DLL/so/dylib handle containing a function address at runtime (with GetModuleHandleEx or dladdr). This could be used to associate some code with the dynamic library which contains it. 
The problem comes With static libraries because every link operation is deferred until the final executable link operation and every function gets its resolved final pointer at this time. We can't then associate any address or function pointer to the static lib.

Multiple inline function pointers get an unique pointer at link time (duplicates will be thrown away). So we cannot use one of them to identify the static library.

Multiple static will get a pointer for each translation unit, which is also not identifying the static library.

My only solution for now is to provide an UUID with -DUUID= different for each static library used in the project, but that would be cool to automatise this with an internal compile time feature/trick.

My question is : is there a trick to uniquely identify a static library at runtime on windows and unix platforms (linux/OSX/iOS/Android...) ?
(not tested yet, but for windows, the "__ImageBase" symbol trick could do the job even if i don't like it, but for other platforms i'm stuck).

To be more precise of what i try to achieve, i'm looking to map at runtime some global variable with the respective static library they belong too.

For example: in lib0.lib built from this lib0.cpp code:

```
namespace {
 AClass global0;
}
```

and in lib1.lib built from this lib1.cpp code:

```
namespace {
 AClass global1;
}
```

I want to be able at runtime to map in a generic way :
- &global0 with "lib0.lib" 
- &global1 with "lib1.lib"

Hope my question is a bit more clear...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to identify version of c/c++ library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542621/is-there-a-way-to-identify-version-of-c-c-library)

Comment: No not a duplicate, i'm not trying to identify a version of a given C++ static library, i'm trying to get something which associates a compiled code with its static library at run-time. For example i would like to associate a static variable in a .cpp with its static library represented by an unique ID. This ID could have any value but this value should be the same every where in the static library code to differentiate it from other linked static libraries)
And it must be a generic way (like dladdr or GetModuleHandleEx for dynamic libs), not dependant from the static library itself.

Comment: @Juicebox, i tried reading it several times, didn't understand the question. What are you associating with?

Comment: Let's say for example that i want to group every address of every static variable in every linked static library in a unique map<uint, void*> where the "uint" will be the static libraries IDs i try to obtain. Is it more clear ? (i'm trying to get an equivalent to the DLL HMODULE but for static libraries, but not only on windows, on unix platforms too, compiled with clang++)

Comment: I'm confused too. What are you **really trying to do**?

Comment: Sorry i meant a multimap<uint, void*> instead of a map<uint, void*>
Which mean in fact :
multimap<static_lib_id, global_static_variable_address>
I try to retrieve information about static library at run-time to sort my objects/addresses by libraries (for my own reasons). Tell me what you don't understand so that i can explain some specific points. I can't be more clear about what i want to do.

Comment: What @selbie wants to is the "my own reasons" part. Static libraries aren't really supposed to be independent entities in the final program, so knowing why you want to associate globals with specific libraries could help us suggest an alternative solution to your underlying problem, one that works with the system instead of against it.

Comment: I have reflection and the reason is to keep reflection context consistent between static and dynamic builds of my libraries. I use the library name in the id string of reflection symbols. I don't know if that helps much though... I wanted to keep the example simple because at the end my problem is "simple" : how to generically associate symbols with their static libraries at runtime, not more, not less.